# How to do email verification after Sign up in Flutter app with .net core API service

Tags: flutter, .net-core, flutter-web, .net-5, rest

I am trying to do sign-up email verification with flutter and the .net API service. I have added the backend service and the verification email sending properly. But I need to show a popup message to the user to notify him the account has been created successfully after clicking the verification link which was sent to his email id. I could not find any way to do this. How can I do this? How to notify the flutter app the verification link is clicked?

Comment: You can use FCM to deliver a foreground notification or you can have an end point(api) that is called to verify user has clicked the link or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Please provide a sample code or any reference.